# Laravel - Extend Cashier vendor package

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-cashier

I not using a User model for my subscriptions so am running into troubles when switching plans as the relationship for the subscription to a model is defined as

```
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the subscription.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        $model = getenv('BRAINTREE_MODEL') ?: config('services.braintree.model');
        return $this->belongsTo($model, 'user_id');
    }
```

which has user_id hardcoded in Subscription.php. https://github.com/laravel/cashier-braintree/blob/2.0/src/Subscription.php

I am using the Braintree version of Cashier but I am sure it is the same with Stripe.

I have edited the vendor package which I know is not best practice and can't be used with automated deployments.

How do I go about extending this class to override the method in Laravel?

I have found plenty of guides on how to extend classes but as this is implemented through a trait I am not aware of a way I can extend this trait?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.